# I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows but I can't see it in Windows' boot menu

Tags: boot, windows

I have a second machine where Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Debian Squeeze are installed on the same HD and when I boot, I have this grub menu where I can choose which partition I will used. It works perfectly! But in my Windows environment that's another story.

Now after making almost everything that I know, to make it work along Windows 7, there is no entry in the boot menu of Windows (I know, Ubuntu use grub but anyway there is surely a way to fix it, access it?). Why there is no Ubuntu entry? Why the installation gave me no error while I have this strange situation of having a "ghost OS" called Ubuntu installed somewhere in my second HD in a partition made especially for it and not being able to access it, starting it, having it working?

Am I wrong? If I am, what's the problem? If I'm not, what's the need of Wubi?

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting the boot menu at all? Or is ir going straight to 7?

If it is, your going to have to modify the bootloader time with msconfig:

1. Open Start
2. type "msconfig"
3. Go to the tab "Boot"
4. Verify that there is a Ubuntu entry in the list.
5. if there is, Look for a option near the right-bottom called "Timeout".
6. If it is 0, set it to about 10 seconds.
7. Restart PC
8. Look for the ubuntu option, then move the arrow keys at the boot menu to it, then press enter.
9. Ubuntu should load.

Try and follow these steps, and it should work.

Comment: Your solution is very good, i tried it but unfortunatly i do not have any Ubuntu entries in the boot tab of my msconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is very good, i tried it but unfortunatly i do not have any Ubuntu entries in the boot tab of my msconfig. Somehow, in my bios (or cmos) option, i have a boot option when i start my pc (before having the windows menu) and i can press F## to enter what it is called "boot option menu" and it lead me to my HD, and also to my usb drives. So i select my second HD, and i had the proper menu of Ubuntu including Windows, where now i can select Ubuntu and starting it properly.

Comment: I found also a utility named EasyBCD 2.2 (wanna try it go to http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/ and select the free version) who can change my boot.cfg and many more things also, even having a grub 2 menu instead of my Windows menu, and it seem to be made from this software. But ..... i consider these possible changes in this part of my HD very sensible (sorry for my bad english i speak french), and i consider that i have to handle this with care. But is there any ways to add an entry in the boot loader config of windows, who can make the ubuntu grub menu accessible ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can chainload the GRUB bootloader with EasyBCD, try finding a option that says chainload, or make a Linux Entry that points to your second HD.

Answer (score 0):

Run a Live Session of Ubuntu (from cd or usb). Once loged in, install the program called "boot repair" (check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Run the program, it will install Grub, and fix everything for you